# Filterings elements of a list

Tags: python, list, filter

I wrote a piece of code which is supposed to filter the content of a clipboard, but i can't make it work.
It takes care of the first filtering step just fine, but the second step sort of throws out some words, but keeps the rest in, and i can't figure out why.

```
import pyperclip

clipboard_content = pyperclip.paste()
separated_sentences = clipboard_content.split('\r\n')
filtered_sentences = list()

for sentence in separated_sentences:
    chopped_sentence = list(sentence)

    if chopped_sentence[0] == "[" or chopped_sentence[0] == "*":
        chopped_sentence.clear()
    else:
        filtered_sentences.append("".join(chopped_sentence))

forbidden_words = ["Map", "Currently", "Server", "Welcome", "F1", "F2", "F3", "dbPoll", "login:", "You", "Notice:"]

for sentence in filtered_sentences:
    index = filtered_sentences.index(sentence)
    words = filtered_sentences[index].split()

    for forbidden_word in forbidden_words:
        if words[0] == forbidden_word:
            filtered_sentences.pop(index)

for sentence in filtered_sentences:
    print(sentence)
```

Here's some sample text to copy:

- Connected!
  Currently
  Server test test
  F1 test
  F2 test
  F3 test
  Server test
  test1: test test
  Map  test
  Notice: test
  dbPoll test test
  login: test test
  test2: test test test
  test3: test test test
  test4: test test test
  You  test test
- test test
  [MESSAGE] test test
- test test test

(I'm sorry, but it sticks together for whatever reason!)

(Edit: The text is supposed to go line under line)

Oddly, the sentence starting with the word "Currently" gets removed, "F1", "F3" ones, too, but stuff like "Notice:" gets ignored. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution,

- Convert `forbidden_words` to `set` for *fast lookup*.

```
forbidden_words = set(["Map", "Currently", "Server", "Welcome", "F1", "F2", 
                       "F3", "dbPoll", "login:", "You", "Notice:"])
```

- Use a list comphrehension to filter out forbidden_words from original text.

```
text = """Connected! Currently Server test test F1..."""

[x for x in text.split() if x not in forbidden_words]
```

Comment: [lets dicuss here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219664/discussion-with-dnm24)

Answer (score 0):

The code left the first line unchecked, checked the next one, and did it alternately til the end. I put in in a "for _ in range()" loop, which fixed the problem.